# PHP, получить данные SOAP из json decode

Tags: php

```
$json = '{"success":true,"data":{"SOAP-ENV:Envelope":{"$":{"xmlns:SOAP-ENV":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"},"SOAP-ENV:Header":"","SOAP-ENV:Body":{"CreatePickupReply":{"$":{"xmlns":"http://fedex.com/ws/pickup/v15"},"HighestSeverity":"SUCCESS","Notifications":{"Severity":"SUCCESS","Source":"disp","Code":"0000","Message":"Success","LocalizedMessage":"Success"},"TransactionDetail":{"CustomerTransactionId":"CreatePickupRequest_v15","Localization":{"LanguageCode":"EN","LocaleCode":"ES"}},"Version":{"ServiceId":"disp","Major":"15","Intermediate":"0","Minor":"0"},"PickupConfirmationNumber":"206","Location":"LNNA"}}}}}';

        $decode = json_decode($json);

        var_dump($decode);
```

Как я могу получить данные, которые нахоядятся за путем `SOAP-ENV:Envelope` -> `SOAP-ENV:Body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) с параметром `associative` объекты JSON будут возвращены как ассоциативные массивы (array)

```
<?php
$json =
    '{"success":true,"data":{"SOAP-ENV:Envelope":{"$":{"xmlns:SOAP-ENV":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"},"SOAP-ENV:Header":"","SOAP-ENV:Body":{"CreatePickupReply":{"$":{"xmlns":"http://fedex.com/ws/pickup/v15"},"HighestSeverity":"SUCCESS","Notifications":{"Severity":"SUCCESS","Source":"disp","Code":"0000","Message":"Success","LocalizedMessage":"Success"},"TransactionDetail":{"CustomerTransactionId":"CreatePickupRequest_v15","Localization":{"LanguageCode":"EN","LocaleCode":"ES"}},"Version":{"ServiceId":"disp","Major":"15","Intermediate":"0","Minor":"0"},"PickupConfirmationNumber":"206","Location":"LNNA"}}}}}';

$decode = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($decode['data']["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]);
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=2d9995a60444c9f64427f6c4dce96dee&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)